# python not working in SQLMAP - No file or directory found (Kali Linux)

Tags: kali-linux, python3, xrdp

I had installed sqlmap inside kali Linux WSL2 , I tried to access the python commands, it says
**bash: python: command not found**

I have python3 installed inside kali. Any idea, please?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/python3-transition/

Comment: Maybe the binary's name is not `python` but `python3` or `python3.9`